# Turn off autofocus for bootstrap-select / select2

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2, bootstrap-select

http://www.bootply.com/YAQrE52K6X

```
    $("#dataCombo").selectpicker({
    multiple:true
    });

    <div class="container">

  <h3>Multiple Select</h3>
  <select id="dataCombo" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" multiple="multiple" style="width:400px;">

    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
    <option value="four">Four</option>
    <option value="five">Five</option>
    <option value="six">Six</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

I want to turn off autofocus so the input does not ask for me to search immediately after clicking the dropdown. Tried to use `.blur` etc... but nothing so far. Looked around for a fix. Moved to use "bootstrap-select" from "select2" due to same problem. The keyboard on devices appears covering the multiple dropdown items

Comment: Do you want to disable the input that allows the search or you only want it to not get auto-focus?

Comment: Not get autofocused - I still want to use the search box but not straight away when clicking dropdown. This will stop the keyboard appearing immediately on devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't able to fix this with bootstrap-select (seems like they have some issues with triggering the `show.bs.select` and `shown.bs.select` events), but since you also mentioned that you tried this with select2, here is a solution for the select2:

```
  $("#dataCombo").select2({
    closeOnSelect: false
  });
  $("#dataCombo").on('select2:open', function () {
    $(document.activeElement).blur()
  });
```

Check this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/yw61h28z/

## Update - 2016/12/05

Managed to get it to work (took some time to play with the focus/blur/targets things).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dataCombo").select2({
    closeOnSelect: false
  });
  $("#dataCombo").one('select2:open', function (e) {
    $(document.activeElement).blur()
  });
  $("#dataCombo").on('select2:close', function(e) {
    if ($(event.target).parents('.select2').length) {
      // The closing was done inside the select2 container
    } else {
      $("#dataCombo").one('select2:open', function (e) {
        $(document.activeElement).blur()
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Here is the update to my original jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/yw61h28z/4/

> **Here is the idea behind the code:**
>   1. The first time the select2 is opened - blur the `input` (but only one time) - this makes sure the select2 menu is opened, but the `input` isn't focused (so the keyboard is not displayed).
>   2. On closing the select2 menu - check the element that caused the close.
>   2.1. If that element is part of the `select2` block - ignore it and close keep closing the menu.
>   2.2 Else - The next time the select2 menu is opened we `blur` the `input` (again - only 1 time).

Comment: thanks for your answer above. This small issue with it is that when you now want to use search you can only manage to type 1 character before it loses focus, because the select opens on type triggering the blur. Any ideas on fix for the fiddle you created?

Answer (score 0):

for bootstrap select picker you can do like this it works for me :

```
$(document).on("change","select.selectpicker",function(){
    $(this).next().next().children(".bs-searchbox").children("input[type='search']").blur()
});
```