# Select2 multi-select search loses focus too quickly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I had an issue with the select2 multi-select on mobiles. The keyboard kept appearing. The fix was to remove auto focus on the search input box to drop straight in to the picklist - see https://jsfiddle.net/yw61h28z/

Now the issue is, if I want to use the input as a search (click in input twice to gain focus) start typing I only manage to type one character before it loses focus due to the picklist opening. When the picklist opens the first fix is applied to lose focus. Not sure what I can do here - maybe add a delay when typeing. Or only apply this:

```
      $("#dataCombo").on('select2:open', function (e, i) {
    $(document.activeElement).blur()
  });
```

on click and exclude from when a user types?

Comment: I think it makes more sense to open a bounty on your previous question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40509189/turn-off-autofocus-for-bootstrap-select

Comment: Done! thanks @Dekel

Comment: I'll give it another try there. It's indeed a tricky one :)